# Powering a Project Tango Tablet with iRobot Create 2

Tags: irobot-create

Project Tango Development Kits come with a mini-dock (see picture below).

I am controlling the iRobot Create 2 by the mounted Tablet using the USB cable provided plugged into the mini-dock. (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/tablet#get_started)).

> The USB 3.0 port on the mini-dock is only functional when the tablet is docked. The port can be used to attach an external memory drive or standard peripherals to the tablet.

I wish to recharge the tablet using the power from the iRobot. The mini dock comes with a port for external charging:

> The mini-dock accepts a power adapter for faster charging (not provided). The power adapter output must be 12V, 2A, and the connector must be a barrel plug with 5.5mm outer diameter, 2.1mm inner diameter, center positive.

Ideally the charging would happen only when the iRobot is also charging, but charging all the time is acceptable.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - No, it is not possible.

None of the motor drivers will deliver 24W, see [link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irobotweb.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2FMainSite%2FPDFs%2FAbout%2FSTEM%2FCreate%2FBatteryPower_2015.pdf%3Fla%3Den).  In addition the power supply that provides charging power to the robot is limited to just over 24W under the best case. See the dock rating on the label (22.5V @ 1.25A).  All of this power is used to charge the robot battery and power the robot electronics to control charging.  Even if you waited until the robot battery was finished charging you would still need to convert the 22.5V to 12V but there is no suitable access to the 22.5V.

You will either have to live with charging your Tango independently from the robot or use a lower power computer (Arduino, RasPi, etc.) to control Create 2.